# BitcoinJ walletTemplate P2WPKH Send payment not working

Tags: java, bitcoin, bitcoinj, segwit

I have tried to use WalletTemplate sub-project inside [bitcoinJ](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj) lib. I have tried p2pkh sends and they work fine. But then I tried to make P2WPKH payment but it failed with the following error message

```
 org.bitcoinj.core.RejectedTransactionException: Reject: tx
 539c7f25b14b20dfad1ad66923fa59bf7531cd1ebda967e8346793fa2464f5dc for
 reason 'non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Signature must be zero for
 failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation)' (64)
```

This behavior doesn't exist before [commit](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/commit/bc46e8518d677088b5b5a3a8dbdefa9958461c90). So I'm not sure how to handle the changes introduced since this change.
I have also create github [issue](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/issues/2006) to get more information but I haven't got any response yet. I have tried code outside of bitcoinj's walletTemplate in another project as follows:

```
    NetworkParameters params = TestNet3Params.get();
    Address destination = Address.fromString(params, strDest);
    Coin value = Coin.parseCoin(strValue);
    SendRequest request = SendRequest.to(destination, value);

    SendResult result = wallet.sendCoins(request);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Issue was solve on github via the latest commit [7c31dcb](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/commit/7c31dcbf99e1d8b6b3d37fb14a3069037b6fc1ca).